# Google maps API, Wordpress plugin, Trying to get Imperial output

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I have downloaded a google maps plugin for wordpress, which outputs in km, but I'm in the UK so I need miles.

I have added the line

```
 unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL
```

to the code

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('origin').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,   
    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL
  };
```

but it still returns km.

Any ideas how I get it to return miles?

Comment: What are you doing with `request`?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what value you are checking but if we are talking about the `Distance` object, the documentation says the `value` property is always returned in meters, while the `text` property is a representation of the value using the `UnitSystem`specified.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance

Otherwise, you always can convert from METRIC to IMPERIAL using your own maths.